# SQL Server TDE: Wildcard and Full-Text Search

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

We have to encrypt an entire SQL server database (customer requirement). The database is accessed in .NET with C#. A custom ORM is in use which creates the corresponding SQL commands.

If the database gets encrypted is the database server still able to handle wildcard or full-text search out of the box although the data have been encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you did the encryption.  If you are using the built in encryption that SQL server ships with, then yes.  If you are encrypting the data *then* storing it in the database server, then no.

Answer (score 0):

TDE is encryption at rest (database file encryption).  it has nothing to do with your queries coming across the wire.